# kendo grid command change button

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How is possible to change button on click in command column?  In my case, there should be "Validate" and "Reset" button that should be displayed as different buttons depending on Status. Function for validating works normally, but there is a problem with applying another class to the button, there is always .valid class. Here is a problem, I don't know where to apply .reset class. Thanks

```
template: 
    '<kendo button class = "k-primary button button-valid"ng-click="OnChangeStateMaterialDefinitionHeaders($event)"> #= Status == ' + STATUS_MDH_VALIDATE + '  ?  " ' + kendo.htmlEncode(txt.TXT_VALIDATE) + '" : "' +  kendo.htmlEncode(txt.TXT_RESET) + '" #</kendo button>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                    '<button ng-click="OnRemoveMaterialDefinitionHeaders($event)">' + kendo.htmlEncode(txt.TXT_SET_VALIDATED) + ' </button>',
```

The other button is not important now, but is a part of this command column.